# Mysql Where Alias equals

Tags: php, mysql

given a table 'my_table' with columns col1,col2. 
Is it possible to write a query like this

```
SELECT col1 as my_alias,col2 FROM my_table WHERE my_alias = 'value'
```

I have tried it but get an unknown column 'my_alias' in where clause.

For the curious, the reason I am doing this is:

I have a table with a composite primary key. When I retrieve information from that table I concatenate the cols that make up the primary key into an Id which can then be used in my url's to identify particular records. Then when I want to return only the given record I select the record where it is = my alias. Not sure if this is a good idea, feel free to comment.

**Note:** The standard way to do this query is:

```
SELECT col1 as my_alias,col2 FROM my_table WHERE col1 = 'value';
```

Comment: You cannot reference column aliases in `WHERE` clauses, it's a rule.

Comment: No you cannot could show show a bit of you table

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not allowed. From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> #### 12.2.8. SELECT Syntax
>
> ...
>
> It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed. See [Section C.5.5.4, “Problems with Column Aliases”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html).

And:

> #### C.5.5.4. Problems with Column Aliases
>
> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses to refer to the column.
>
> ...
>
> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.

---

To fix it you should write your query as follows:

```
SELECT col1 AS my_alias, col2
FROM my_table
WHERE col1 = 'value'
```

If `col1` is not actually a single column but a more complicated expression then you should be aware that using it in your WHERE clause will most likely prevent efficient usage of an index and result in a full scan. This could hurt the performance of your application if the table grows large.

Comment: Of course the method you have shown is how you should do the query. I simplified the question for the purposes of getting an answer to a specific question. I will update my question to reflect that.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with an old piece of code that worked well with MySQL 5.0. After updating to 5.5, I get the error. I have no clue how that worked, but it did.
If anybody knows if there is a way of making this happen again, that would be really great.

Answer (score 2):

It's not directly possible but you could use a subselect and use the column alias in the outer select:

```
select my_alias, col2
from (SELECT col1 as my_alias,col2 FROM my_table) as x
WHERE my_alias = 'value'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in HAVING clause.